# CKEditor disappears on partial postback

Tags: ckeditor

I have a page that shows a ckeditor in an update panel. My page is as follows:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" ID="ToolkitScriptManager" EnablePartialRendering="true"></cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Hello"></asp:Label><br />
        <br />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <script src="../../../../../ckeditor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

                <asp:TextBox class="ckeditor" ID="tbEditorHeader" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="80" Rows="4"></asp:TextBox>

                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
                </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</form>
```

Has anyone seen this issue? Any known solutions?

Thanks for the help!!